# One of SESSION variables gets changed

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am developing a web application with per-role user interface and functionality. In `users` table I have a `role` column, an `enum`, which stores each user's role. In the login script if a matching record for the user/pass is found I set a `SESSION['role']` variable to the value of the record's role field. Along with the role, I also store several other bits of data, such as the display_name in other `SESSION` variables. Then, `SESSION['role']` is used throughout the application to send the correct user interface to the browser and enforce access rules.

This all works fine on my localhost, but on the remote server, `SESSION['role']` works just the first time - i.e. the correct user interface is sent to the browser. After that point, `SESSION['role']` somehow changes to a different (existing) role, and as a result access rules do not allow the functions to be available. What is even more bizarre is that only `SESSION['role']` changes and `SESSION['displayname']` or `SESSION['username']` remain intact.

I am not setting `SESSION` variables anywhere other than `login.php`. Any ideas where I should look for potential causes is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you have an assignment in an `if` statement?

Comment: And you're sure it's the same code in both environments?

Comment: @WaleedKhan, good candidate, thanks! I pray to gods it's this.

Comment: Do you have another application running on the prod server which uses the same `session_name()`? If so, it can overwrite your session vars.  Set different names with `session_name('app1'), session_name('app2')`

Comment: @Ddorda, I have checked many times, I re-uploaded everything several times, but still the same.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, the app is on a shared hosting, but the possibility that another app uses `$_SESSION['role'] = Manager|Therapist|Receptionist|...` is *very* low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. On the prod server `register_globals` was on (which is a tasteless choice for PHP 5.3.6 by the way).

However, I did not suspect that being the cause, because I was not aware of how it affected the super globals. I though having `register_globals` on was equivalent to adding this block of code at the beginning of all your scripts:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $kn => $val) eval("$kn = $val;");
same for other super globals ...
```

In other words, I thought having `$_SESSION['role']` defined and equal to `'Manager'` had the same effect as this line:

```
$role = $_SESSION['role'];
or
$role = 'Manager';
```

But this is only *half of the story* as the second line below

```
$role = $_SESSION['role'];
$role = 'Something else';
```

does not affect the `SESSION['role']` and it's value would still be whatever it was. But if `register_globals` is on, changing `$role` would change `$_SESSION['role']`.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your database structure is the same. Most notably that the ENUM has the same roles / identifiers. If you specify a value that's not valid, SQL will fail in "STRICT MODE", but otherwise it will fall back to one of the values.

(Tip: always develop in "STRICT MODE" unless there's some reason not to. Then you don't get strung when distributing to live).

If you have a separate table with the roles (such as a LEFT JOIN) check that too.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, so +1 and thanks! But this is unlikely to be the issue -- actually I have added a bypass to record checking in `login.php` for ease of testing and using `meta-ROLENAME` will log in as a valid user of role `ROLENAME`. And the issue is present for these logins too.